# Is it possible to set a whole hard disk(partition) as iscsi target?

Tags: iscsi

till now I defined just image files.
But I have a logical partition and I'd like to share it by iscsi.
Is it possible or I am limited to single files?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can share any block device as iscsi target. That is the whole purpose of iscsi. It is a special feature that you can also share disk images stored in files.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the lun in the ietd.conf?

Comment: Wouldn't be better to expand the question and show what doesn't work for you? My impression was that stackexchange users are expected to do at least some research before asking.